# Spring data and quartz Autowiring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I use the following QuartzConfig configuration class to autowire spring data with quartz, this configuration class works well and fire job once I run project with no errors, but I want to fire jobs manually by the following spring controller but I got @autowire error with spring data

Quartz Job

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class JobOne implements Job {
    @Autowired
    TestrecordRepository testrecordRepository;
    @Autowired
    ScoreRepository scoreRepository;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("Job one!"); 
        List<Testrecord> records=testrecordRepository.findAll();
        for (Testrecord t : records) {
            Testrecord testrecord = new Testrecord();
            testrecord.setValue_integer(t.getValue_integer());
            testrecord.setId(t.getId());
            RuleExecutor ruleExecutor = new RuleExecutor();
            Score score = ruleExecutor.processRules(testrecord);
            scoreRepository.save(score);    
        }
    }
}
```

configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean quartzSchedulerjobOne() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean quartzScheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();

        quartzScheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);

        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        quartzScheduler.setJobFactory(jobFactory);

        Trigger[] triggers = {
                processjobOneTrigger().getObject()
        };

        quartzScheduler.setTriggers(triggers);

        return quartzScheduler;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean processjobOne() {
        JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        jobDetailFactory.setJobClass(JobOne.class);
        jobDetailFactory.setDurability(true);
        return jobDetailFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean processjobOneTrigger() {
        CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setJobDetail(processjobOne().getObject());
        cronTriggerFactoryBean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * * * ?");
        return cronTriggerFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Spring controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void test(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
            QuartzConfig.class);
    Scheduler scheduler = (Scheduler)context.getBean("quartzSchedulerjobOne");

}
```

eclipse console

```
[ERROR] org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'DEFAULT.processJobTwo'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job instantiation failed
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:45) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:134) ~[quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:387) [quartz-2.1.5.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at com.innvo.quartz.AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.createJobInstance(AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.AdaptableJobFactory.newJob(AdaptableJobFactory.java:41) ~[spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository com.innvo.quartz.JobTwo.testrecordRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:561) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.innvo.repository.TestrecordRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you add that class TestrecordRepository ? The log clearly says it cant autowire it

Answer (score 0):

from the error log that you posted , its clear that its looking for a bean which has not been wrapped by spring.The first bean com.innvo.quartz.JobOne.testrecordRepository where is defined? Are you sure its in the package scan? The bean name quartzSchedulerjobOne that you want to get from the application context , is anywhere defined??
Also why you try to get the Scheduler from the application context , and you dont autowire it to the controller? The scheduler has to be singleton and he will be responsible to start a new job.

Comment: quartzSchedulerjobOne bean  defined in QuartzConfig class this bean call automatically once I deploy and all autowire beans work ,but I want to call this bean by controller

Comment: well for sure , the first think that must be resolved is the problem of autowiring the com.innvo.quartz.JobOne.testrecordRepository class. Could you share the code or a snipped , where this class is being used? are you sure that its being wrapped by spring?

Comment: autowiring works with no probelm with QuartzConfig class configuration beans,I wonder why it don't work when I try to call QuartzConfig beans by controller

Comment: then you have confused the contexts or you dont load them properly, are you sure about QuartzConfig , that its loaded? and the applicationContext is being passed ?